# parameter "name" doesn't pass in my spring back app

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

Hello I have some diffculties to pass a String parameter in my springboot app. I use Postman to give a "name" parameter ! And everytime it's says me that " Required String parameter 'name' is not present" !

And even if I delete the @RequestParam, a System.print.out says that the value is null ...

MyProductController

```
    @GetMapping("/searchProducts" )
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Product> listSearchedProducts(@RequestParam String name){
        System.out.println(name);
        return productService.getSearchedProducts(name);
    }
```

[And the postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ0GG.png)

Comment: In postman you are sending the post request so use @PostMapping, Or Change the RequestURL

Comment: in postman put the name parameters in params tab not in body. You are trying to send get request with json body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request parameter can be query param like:

```
/searchProducts?name=someone
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this image how you set the parameter on postman

[image]

key -> name

value -> value of the name param

Answer (score 0):

Ok the both answers were good I have to change to post I don't know why I haven't noticed a big mistake like this and I change the postman request to send the good (key-value) Thank you guys :)